# Getting Heroku's config vars to work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a node app that has a line like this:

```
var ip = process.env.IP || 'http://localhost';
```

I am using it with `passport-facebook` node package to define the callback from Facebook authentication:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
callbackURL: ip + ":" + port + "/auth/facebook/callback"
},
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // asynchronous verification, for effect...
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

It seems that Heroku doesn't know `process.env.IP` so I went ahead and defined a `config var` in Heroku:

```
heroku config:add process.env.IP=http://app.mydomain.com
```

Debugging the server I see that ip is not what I want but it's `http://localhost` same as I defined as the fallback in the first line of code.

How do I get node to read the config var correctly from heroku ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want to use `heroku config:set IP=http://app.mydomain.com`; it defines an environment variable called `IP`, which you access in Node.js via `process.env.IP`. See [Setting up config vars for a deployed application](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) for more information.

Comment: Why an earth isn't this clearer in the docs?! The sample app is on 5000 so I assumed all were

Comment: What I was looking for in `node`. As opposed to `netlify`, the `process.env.config_var_heroku` does not work locally. So you need locally a file like `.env` to declare the vars in 2 places.